# Select from table1 sum table2.column sum table3.column based on table accountNumbers

Tags: c#, mysql

I have challenge for the past 2 days with this query. 
I searched everywhere but in futility.
I have 3 tables; `customers`, `transactions`and `withdrawals`.
Customers table has AccountNumber, Names etc, transactions have FK Account Number and Amount and withdrawals has FK AccountNumber and Amount.

I just want to select AccountNumber, Names from customers and `SUM` the corresponding transactions Amount and SUM the withdrawals Amount AccountNumber by AccountNumber.

Currently I am forced to run

```
SELECT AccountNumber,FirstName,LastName,Town,Contact
FROM customers
WHERE status = 1
ORDER BY AccountNumber ASC
```

Load data into datatable and loop over it to select:

```
SELECT SUM(SusuAmount)
FROM transactions
WHERE AccountNumber = " + account + "
  AND Approval = 1`
```

and this:

```
SELECT SUM(ValueAmount)
FROM withdrawals
WHERE AccountNumber = " + account + "
  AND Approval = 1`
```

Please kindly suggest a single query to help do this once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT cus.AccountNumber,cus.FirstName,cus.LastName,cus.Town,cus.Contract,Sum(trans.SusuAmount) AS TransactionAmount,SUM(widraw.ValueAmount) AS WithdrawalsAmount FROM customers AS cus 
LEFT JOIN transactions AS tran ON (trans.AccountNumber=cus.AccountNumber AND cus.Approval=1)
LEFT JOIN withdrawals AS widraw ON (widraw.AccountNumber=cus.AccountNumber AND widraw.Approval=1) 
WHERE cus.status=1 ORDER BY cus.AccountNumber ASC
```